# How to return floating point number in windows nasm

Tags: c++, assembly, nasm

I want to pass a floating point variable from CPP file to asm file, do some math on it and return it back. It works for integers, for doubles it shows strange output (-1.#INDOO)

It should work for -f win32 option in NASM (working on VS2008 express edition and nasm)

I have checked if it works for integers, it does. When I try it for doubles, neither `mov eax, [ebp + 8]  ret` nor `movsd xmm0, [ebp + 8]  ret` work

cpp file

```cpp
extern "C" double bar(double k);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double w[6];

    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        w[j] = bar(3.5);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", w[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

assembly file

```
section .text
global _bar
_bar:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    movsd xmm0, [ebp + 8]

        ; or mov eax, [ebp + 8]

    leave
    ret
```

For now it should return 3.5 in for each element, but it returns -1.#INDOO

Comment: 32 bit calling convention uses the FPU for return value. See [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/floating-point-coprocessor-and-calling-conventions). `fld qword ptr [ebp+8]` or similar should work.

Comment: @Jester indeed it worked. `fld qword [ebp + 8]`

Comment: The problem is when i do ```movsd xmm4, [ebp + 8] \n
 fld qword [xmm4]```. It throws `error: invalid effective address`. Any idea? `fld qword xmm4` doesn't work too

Comment: The FPU doesn't talk to the XMM registers.  Since you're running 32 bit code, the XMM registers might not even exist on the hardware.

Comment: Also `[xmm4]` would be a memory reference which doesn't make much sense with an xmm register. To transfer from `xmm` to fpu you need to go through memory.

Comment: Well, the thing I need to do is to perform: ([ebp + 16] - [ebp + 24]) * [ebp + 32] * [ebp + 40] + [ebp + 8] (all variables are doubles), but honestly it doesn't work with both xmm (as you said I shouldn't use it), eax (when multiplying it says it has problem with size). So I am stuck

Comment: You can do your maths using `xmm` **if** you know your cpu has SSE support and then you can transfer to fpu as the last step. Otherwise use fpu instructions. Consult a reference or a [tutorial](http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/).

Comment: @Jester, thank you very very much, i really appreciate your help. Everything worked. And i haven't used xmm -> ```fld qword [ebp + 16]
 fsub qword [ebp + 24]
 fmul qword [ebp + 32]
 fmul qword [ebp + 8]
 fadd qword [ebp + 40]``` returns what it should. You are my hero :D